# php cron job execute javascript as well

Tags: php, javascript, cron

I have a cron job running a php script, but theres some html and javascript that I need to execute for the actual script to work.

Converting the javascript to php isnt an option.

Basically I need it to act as though a person is viewing the page every time the cronjob runs.

EDIT:
the script uses javascript from a different site to encrypt some passwords so it is able to log into my account on the site, and the javascript is thousands of lines. The way the script flows is: Send data to website>get the data it sends back>use sites javascript to alter data>set html form value to value of data returned by javascript function>submit html form to get info back to php>send data to log me in. I know the code is very shoddy but its the only way i could think to do it without having to rewrite all the javascript they use to encrypt the password to php

Comment: How exactly does one execute HTML? What are you specifically trying to accomplish in your cron job? Because it seems like you may be going about this the wrong way. Give us a little more information about your intentions and you'll probably get a better solution.

Comment: What's wrong with converting it to PHP? Surely if the javascript **must** be called, then it calls a PHP script somewhere?

Comment: the script uses javascript from a different site to encrypt some passwords so it is able to log into my account on the site, and the javascript is thousands of lines. The way the script flows is: Send data to website>get the data it sends back>use sites javascript to alter data>set html form value to value of data returned by javascript function>submit html form to get info back to php>send data to log me in. I know the code is very shoddy but its the only way i could think to do it without having to rewrite all the javascript they use to encrypt the password to php.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question.

Comment: @Max,  update your question rather than posting a comment.

Comment: Is the third party site a service that exposes an API, or is it just externally hosted javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Yau can try [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) to run JavaScript code on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is the only way to run Javascript server-side.

Comment: How exactly do we run this through cron?

Comment: If you can add a shell script or any other commend with arguments to your cron job, you can do somehting like `/path/to/node path/to/your/script.js`

Answer (score 1):

install your favorite web browser, and then have the cron job run the browser with the url as an argument.

something like

```
/usr/bin/firefox www.example.com/foo.html
```

you'll probably want to wait a minute or so and then kill the processes, or determine a better way to find when it finishes.

Comment: this is something I thought of originally but I have a cheap webhost running this script and I dont have the ability to install anything.

Comment: I would try. I bet you can. Spending effort installing a browser is probably must less effort than other solutions.

Answer (score -3):

cronjobs always runs on server side only. when there is no client side - how can you expect javascript to work really???

anyway solution is: use cronjob to run another php script - which in fact calls the php script you want to run using CURL.
e.g. file1.php - file you want to execute and expect the javascript on that page to work.

file2.php - another file you create ... in this file use curl to call the file1.php ( make sure you provide full http:// path  like you type in browser - you can pass values like get/post methods on html forms do as well ).   in your cronjob - call file2.php.

Make sure curl is available and not any firewall rule blocking http calls i.e. port 80 calls to same server. Most of the servers both conditions above are fulfilled.

**----------   sorry guys -  Kristian Antonsen is right - so dont consider this as full answer at the moment. However I am leaving this on as someone might have food for thoughts from this -----**

Comment: -1. CURL connects to a webserver just as if you had connected through a telnet client. No HTML is parsed and nor is any JavaScript executed.

Comment: This wouldn't work, it would still be executed server-side, therefore all Javascript wouldn't be executed.